# Как растянуть изображеие, и как центрировать изображение?

Tags: html, css

1. Как Растянуть Изображение `id="picture1"` до левого края?
2. Что я сделал не так с изображением `id="picture2"`, что оно не находится по центру.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 84px;
  background-color: white;
}

.banner {
  height: 570px;
}

.banner img {
  float: right;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 99px;
}

.contentMain {}

.contentCaption {
  color: #515151;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.contetnMain img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="header">

  </div>

  <div class="banner">
    <img id="picture1" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/70729/b0f5ed0d-e398-4a2a-9b08-f4fdad86d054/s1200" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentMain">
      <img id="picture2" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1337375/b7e6f3dd-e1ef-47d5-a957-757ee731c61e/s1200" alt="">
    </div>
    <h1 class="contentCaption">Our work is the presentation of our capabilities.
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>

</div>
```

---

Чуть не забыл про CSS код, который в теге style записал

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Растянуть изображение можно указав его в качестве фона с наилучшим заполнением

```
background: url('url') center / cover
```

Отцентрировать вторую картинку в вашем примере ожно просто указав

```
text-align: center;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 84px;
  background-color: white;
}

.banner {
  height: 570px;
  background: url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/70729/b0f5ed0d-e398-4a2a-9b08-f4fdad86d054/s1200') center / cover;
}

.banner img {
  float: right;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 99px;
}

.contentMain {
  text-align: center;
}

.contentCaption {
  color: #515151;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.contetnMain img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="header">

  </div>

  <div class="banner">

  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentMain">
      <img id="picture2" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1337375/b7e6f3dd-e1ef-47d5-a957-757ee731c61e/s1200" alt="">
    </div>
    <h1 class="contentCaption">Our work is the presentation of our capabilities.
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо.

Остался только один вопрос, почему если поставить на фон изображение из интернета, то трюк работает, а если из папки с HTML-документом, то нет?

Comment: с растягиванием?

Comment: Да. С растягиванием.

Comment: а как не работает? Не растягивается? Или растягивается, но не так?

Comment: Растягиваются ваше и другие изображения, которые вставляются ссылкой из интернета, а те что в папке с HTML-документом лежат не отображаются.

Comment: а как свои указываете? Путь надо указывать или абсолютный или относительно местоположения css файла

Comment: Что абсолютный, что относительный не работают. Проверял на ошибки в названии, но все написал верно, а отображаться - не отображается.

Comment: можете показать, как пишете?

Comment: Да, конечно.

   ` .banner {
 height: 570px;
 background: url('img/Layer_15.png') center / cover;
    } `

и

   ` .banner {
 height: 570px;
 background: url('Layer_15.png') center / cover;
    } `

Comment: попробуйте указать от корня сайта, начиная с `/`. Если папка img лежит в корне сайта, то `background: url('/img/Layer_15.png')`

Comment: Премного вам благодарен.